# Mailchimp/Mandrill and Handlebars changing preview text

Tags: handlebars.js, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm working with MailChimps Mandrill to send transnational emails with handlebars. The whole setup is done and the emails send absolutely fine - but when they arrive they still have the default Mailchimp template string for the preview text that look like:

```
|*MC_PREVIEW*|
```

Is anyone aware of a way to remove this from showing or change it? Currently I have to go into the code of the email in Mandrill and remove the block of code myself - wondering if there is a way to do that from Mailchimps end at all as it's a bit tedious every time an email template is updated and exported back to Mandrill to go in and remove it again.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue, and what helped me was first changing the Mandrill default merge tags to Handlebars, then re-exporting the templates from Mailchimp back to Mandrill.

This converts all *|Mailchimp|* style merge tags in the code of the email into {{handlebars}}-style.

**Important Edit:**

If your Mailchimp templates are using handlebars to define the merge tags, these will get escaped like so:

\{{mergeTag}}

You will either have to manually delete these backslashes to get the tags to work again, OR reformat the merge tags in Mailchimp to be in the *|MAILCHIMP|* style before exporting.

If you choose the latter, when converting a camelCase merge tag to Mailchimp style, just put it in all caps.

E.g. {{mergeTag}} becomes *|MERGETAG|*

Comment: Great thanks Jamie, i'll give this a try when I next need to make some changes

Comment: Do take a look at my edit - I've added some extra info that you'll need to avoid breaking your templates!

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same issue and wrote a little lambda http endoint that we can trigger via slack integration to fix all our mandrill templates:

```js
const mailchimpFactory = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_transactional');

const mailchimp = mailchimpFactory(process.env.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY);

function fixTemplate({ name, code }) {
  const regex = /\*\|MC_PREVIEW_TEXT\|\*/ig; // regexr.com/69390
  const fixedBody = code.replace(regex, '');
  console.log(`Updating ${name}`);
  return mailchimp.templates.update({
    name,
    code: fixedBody,
  });
}

// removes all mailchimp preview merge variables from all
// templates in mandrill (since we're using handlebars)
async function fixAllTemplates(event) {

  const templates = await mailchimp.templates.list();
  await Promise.all(templates.map(fixTemplate));
  const templateList = templates.map(({ name }) => `\n> ${name}`).join('');

  const msg = `*Mandrill Template Fixer:* Updated ${templates.length} templates. ${templateList}`;
  console.log(msg);
  return { statusCode: 200, body: msg };
}

module.exports = { fixAllTemplates };
```